# Need to correctly install Netgear network pccard FA510 on xubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, ethernet, netgear

I checked the **ubuntu compatibility table** and apparently is not supported even then when it was being sold. Can someone guide me through the steps on installing it? I can't find information on the internet and yahoo. It's a PCMCIA card not a usb card.

here is my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
link-speed 100
link-duplex full
ethernet-autoneg off
```

---

Can anyone help me? I got the product ID and vendor ID for this Digital Equipment Corporation and ethernet card. Got the following from lspci -vmmnn command without sudo and then input this output into the h-node.org site to find the IDs.

```
Slot:   02:00.0
Class:  Ethernet controller [0200]
Vendor: Digital Equipment Corporation [1011]
Device: DECchip 21142/43 [0019]
SVendor:    Netgear [1385]
SDevice:    FA510 [2100]
Rev:    41
```

These are the IDs obtained:

```
ethernet-card - DECchip 21142/43
 * device type: Ethernet controller
 * vendor: Digitial Equipment Corporation
 * VendorID:ProductID code of the device 1011:0019
```

i'm doing this to obtain the chipset model so I can install it on Xubuntu 16.04. Can anyone tell me what my chipset is?

here is the output of the lspci command:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
Subsystem: Netgear FA510 [1385:2100]
Kernel driver in use: tulip
Kernel modules: tulip
06:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ULi Electronics Inc. USB 1.1 Controller [10b9:5237] (rev 03)
```

Comment: Please leave the code formatting in place - this works best for displaying files like your /etc/network/interfaces file.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know all the codes, I tried formatting the text the best I could.